# Using custom polymer element inside paper-datatable-column

Tags: datatable, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, custom-element

I am trying to use < paper-datatable-column > . Inside it I have to use my own polymer element but for some reason its not showing up.

```
<paper-datatable id="datatable" data="{{users}}" selectable multi-selection selected-items="{{selectedItems}}" on-row-tap="rowTapped">
        <paper-datatable-column header="risk" type="Number" property="risk" sortable>
            <risk-codes riskcolor={{value}}></risk-codes>
        </paper-datatable-column>
 </paper-datatable>
```

Where < risk-codes > is my custom polymer element. Which is defined below :

```
<template is="dom-if" if={{riskcolor}}>
   <div class="fab red">
     <paper-ripple class="circle" recenters></paper-ripple>
   </div>
</template>
```

And here is the script of < risk-codes > :

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'risk-codes',

    properties: {
      riskcolor:{
        type:Number
      }
    } 
  }); //end-polymer
```

Answer (score 0):

I added < template is="dom bind" > in my custom element and inside it I had put the rest of the code. This did the trick. Strange because i have many custom elements where i am not using "dom-bind" but it works. Maybe because < risk-codes > expects a property from its parent element so it needs to be bound to the DOM. Just a guess, not sure if i am right.